# Fast ndarray boolean intersection

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two 3D boolean arrays of the same shape (let's say `(512,512,512)`).
I'd like to check if the `True` region of one array is completely included in the second.

Right now the best I've come up with is:

```
np.all((A * B) == A)
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Unfortunately this goes inside an inner loop I'm not able to optimize further, so the more I shave from this the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** If they are boolean arrays, `AND-ing` might be better than multiplication -

```
((A & B) == A).all()
```

**Approach #2 :** Another with counting of True values -

```
np.count_nonzero(A & B) == np.count_nonzero(A)
```

**Runtime test -**

```
In [225]: A = np.random.rand(512,512,512)>0.5
     ...: B = np.random.rand(512,512,512)>0.5

In [226]: %timeit np.all((A * B) == A)
     ...: %timeit ((A & B) == A).all()
     ...: %timeit np.count_nonzero(A & B) == np.count_nonzero(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 169 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 57.7 ms per loop
```

---

**Approach #3 :** Short-circuiting at numba level basically looking for if there's any `A` True, for which the corresponding `B` isn't -

```
from numba import njit 

@njit
def numba_app(a, b):
    l = len(a)
    out = True
    for i in range(l):
        if a[i] & ~b[i]:
            out = False
            break
    return out

out = numba_app(A.ravel(), B.ravel())
```

The timings with this `Short-circuiting` method would depend on the data.

Comment: Cool, are you sure approach #2 really does the intersection? Not really my case, but if the two array have the same number of holes in different positions it could still evaluate to true even if they don't match.

Comment: @filippo If they have same number of holes in different positions, `A & B` would have lesser True values than the True values in `A`. That's why it works. The important thing is I am counting Trues on `A & B`. Maybe you got confused there.

Comment: uh, you're right! it's probably time to take a break and have a coffee... thank you